# how to Introduce other proto files?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

My question: The dependency could not be found in the generated file.
[image: result]

This is my project structure:

```
./api
├── auth
│   └── service
│       └── v1
│           ├── auth.pb.go
│           └── auth.proto
└── ws
    └── v1
        └── ws.proto
```

auth.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package api.auth.service.v1;
import "api/ws/v1/ws.proto";
option go_package = "api/auth/service/v1;v1";

service Auth {
  rpc UserRegister(UserRegisterReq) returns(UserRegisterResp);
}

message CommonResp{
  int32   errCode = 1;
  string  errMsg = 2;
}

message UserRegisterReq {
  api.ws.v1.UserInfo userInfo = 1;
  string operationID = 2;
}

message UserRegisterResp {
  CommonResp CommonResp = 1;
}
```

ws.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package api.ws.v1;
option go_package = "api/ws/v1;v1";

message UserInfo{
  string userID = 1;
  string nickname = 2;
  string faceURL = 3;
  int32 gender = 4;
  string phoneNumber = 5;
  uint32 birth = 6;
  string email = 7;
  string ex = 8;
  string createIp = 9;
  uint32 createTime = 10;
  string LastLoginIp =11;
  uint32 LastLoginTime = 12;
  int32  LoginTimes = 13;
  int32 LoginLimit = 14;
  int32 appMangerLevel = 15;
  int32  globalRecvMsgOpt = 16;
  string  invitationCode = 17;
}
```

go.mod:

```
module Janna-IM

go 1.17

require (
    github.com/go-kratos/kratos/v2 v2.5.0
    github.com/google/wire v0.5.0
    google.golang.org/genproto v0.0.0-20220524023933-508584e28198
    google.golang.org/grpc v1.46.2
    google.golang.org/protobuf v1.28.0
)

require (
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.5.4 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/logr v1.2.3 // indirect
    github.com/go-logr/stdr v1.2.2 // indirect
    github.com/go-playground/form/v4 v4.2.0 // indirect
    github.com/golang/protobuf v1.5.2 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0 // indirect
    github.com/imdario/mergo v0.3.12 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel v1.9.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk v1.9.0 // indirect
    go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace v1.9.0 // indirect
    golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20220520000938-2e3eb7b945c2 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sync v0.0.0-20220513210516-0976fa681c29 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220520151302-bc2c85ada10a // indirect
    golang.org/x/text v0.3.7 // indirect
    gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0 // indirect
)
```

I executed this command `$ protoc --proto_path=. --go_out=. ./api/auth/service/v1/auth.proto` at the root of the project.

After executing this command, you will get a new file `auth.pb.go`, The expected error will occur in this file.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Read here on WHY do not post screenshots of code :). https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: With `go_package = "api/ws/v1"` you have instructed `protoc-gen-go` to generate the output as the package `api/ws/v1` which it has done. When using [modules](https://go.dev/ref/mod), which I assume you are, you need to specify the full path (which will start with whatever is in the `module` line in your `go.mod`). Please show us your `go.mod` and also the output from `go build`.

Comment: Thank you for optimizing the problem that I described. : - )

Comment: I have shown `go.mod`

Comment: OK - assuming your `go.mod` is in your `.` folder your should be setting `go_package = "Janna-IM/api/ws/v1"` (or similar for other proto files). Note that I'm assuming that you are putting the result of `protoc` into the correct folders (this can be simplified using something like `--go_out=module=Janna-IM:.`)

Comment: tks u reply. I have modified go_package in auth.proto and ws.proto to `option go_package = "Janna-IM/api/auth/service/v1;v1";` and `option go_package = "Janna-IM/api/ws/v1;v1 ";`
`go.mod` is in my `.` folder. I exec command `$ protoc --proto_path=. --go_out=. ./api/auth/service/v1/auth.proto`. But got the errors 
`Janna-IM/api/ws/v1/ws.proto: File not found.`
,`api/auth/service/v1/auth.proto:2:1: Import "Janna-IM/api/ws/v1/ws.proto" was not found or had errors.` and 
`api/auth/service/v1/auth.proto:18:3: "api.ws.v1.UserInfo" is not defined.`

Comment: The only impact changing the `go_package` should have is to change the package names used for importing and the locations the output files are written (it should not impact how `.proto` files are located) so I'm guessing something else changed. Please don't try to post code/errors in the comments (it's very hard to read!) - edit your question with the updated details.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. `go_package`. I was reminded of what it stood for. The key to solving this problem is `go_package` and `$protoc` Execution position of the command line. Now I've made it! happy code.

Answer (score 1):

Execute it at the root directory.

`$cd Janna-IM`

`$protoc -I=. --go_out=../../ ws/v1/ws.proto`

`$protoc -I=. --go_out=. auth/service/v1/auth.proto`

auth.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package pbAuth;
option go_package = "auth/service/v1;pbAuth";

import "ws/v1/ws.proto";

service Auth {
  rpc UserRegister(UserRegisterReq) returns(UserRegisterResp);
}

message CommonResp{
  int32   errCode = 1;
  string  errMsg = 2;
}

message UserRegisterReq {
  server_api_params.UserInfo userInfo = 1;
  string operationID = 2;
}

message UserRegisterResp {
  CommonResp CommonResp = 1;
}
```

ws.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package server_api_params;
option go_package = "Janna-IM/api/ws/v1;server_api_params";

message UserInfo{
  string userID = 1;
  string nickname = 2;
}
```

How import is written depends on where in terminal the protoc command.

Comment: "Execute it at the root directory" just FYI that's only a requirement because of the `-I=.` - if you specify the full path to the root directory there then you can run the command from anywhere e.g. `-i/home/code/projectX`.